# ruby array separate "duplicates"

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I have this Array of words with a mix of caps and non-caps letters (and number sometimes ) :

`my_array = ['ZV2', '4Q3', 'abDc', 'zQ2', 'Def', '4q3', 'Abdc', 'ABDC', 'def', 'zv2', 'DeF', 'zV2', 'DEF']`

I wanted to separate in several arrays that don't have duplicate words:

`my_array1 = ['ZV2', '4Q3', 'abDc', 'zQ2', 'Def']`

`my_array2 = ['4q3', 'Abdc', 'def', 'zv2']`

`my_array3 = ['ABDC', 'DeF', 'zV2']`    and

`my_array4 = ['DEF']`

What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: You should edit to clarify your question. (It’s an interesting one.) If you do I will vote to reopen,

Comment: `array.each_with_object([]) { |s,a| d=s.downcase; i = a.find_index { |i| a[i].key?(d) ==false }; i.nil? ? (a << { d=> s }) : a[i][d] = s }.map(&:values)`. I wrote this on a phone so I didn’t test, so maybe I made a small mistake. Can another reader check my code? –

Comment: I don't know what details you want. I put the desired output. The desired output will be used in another process. I could not figured out how to get to the desired output that is why I ask the question.

Comment: You can use an example to elaborate your question, but it generally is not sufficient to tell readers what you would like to do. For example, `my_array.to_a` creates a collection of arrays that do not contain case-indifferent duplicates, but I don't think that's what you want. You need to begin with a statement of your problem in words that is complete and unambiguous. For example,...

Comment: ...(assuming my understanding is correct), "Given an array of strings, `my_array`, I wish to create an array `partition` that contains arrays of elements from `my_array` such that: 1) `partition.flatten` contains all the elements of `my_array`; 2) for each element `a` of `partition`, the array `a.map { |s| s.downcase }` contains no duplicates; and 3) the number of elements of `partition` is as small as possible." Sounds like legalese, eh? You might not like that wording but I believe it meets the tests of completeness and clarify. You can use it if you wish.

Comment: I misspoke in the first of my my two previous comments. `my_array.map { |s| [s] }` creates a collection of arrays that do not contain...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters of the question are fairly open to interpretation, but here's one approach: group the array by the downcase of the value:

```rb
> d = my_array.group_by(&:downcase).values
> pp d
[["ZV2", "zv2", "zV2"],
 ["4Q3", "4q3"],
 ["abDc", "Abdc", "ABDC"],
 ["zQ2"],
 ["Def", "def", "DeF", "DEF"]]
```

This gives you an array of arrays, each containing all the duplicates. From here, the solution should be relatively straightforward: given this list of "rows", you want a list of "columns". You can construct your output arrays by creating new arrays, taking the *n*th element of each array until you don't get any elements.

One (non-optimal, in case this is homework!) way to do this would be to pad all your arrays to a common length, then to transpose the result:

```rb
d = my_array.group_by(&:downcase).values
max_len = d.map(&:length).max
padded = d.map {|v| v.fill(nil, v.length..max_len) }

pp padded
[["ZV2", "zv2", "zV2", nil, nil],
 ["4Q3", "4q3", nil, nil, nil],
 ["abDc", "Abdc", "ABDC", nil, nil],
 ["zQ2", nil, nil, nil, nil],
 ["Def", "def", "DeF", "DEF", nil]]
```

Now you simply transpose your array of arrays and compact out any nils:

```rb
padded.transpose.map(&:compact).select(&:any?)
=> [["ZV2", "4Q3", "abDc", "zQ2", "Def"], ["zv2", "4q3", "Abdc", "def"], ["zV2", "ABDC", "DeF"], ["DEF"]]
```

This is hardly the most elegant approach, but it illustrates the idea. You may be able to use this to conceive of better solutions.

Comment: If you use [Array#zip](https://ruby-doc.org//core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-zip) (rather than `transpose`) you don't need to pad the arrays. For example, `a1 = [1,2,3,4]; a2 = [7,8]; a3 = [4,5,6]; a = [a1, a2, a3]; a.shift.zip(*a) #=> [[1, 7, 4], [2, 8, 5], [3, nil, 6], [4, nil, nil]]`. The only requirement is that the `zip`'s receiver (here `a1`) be no smaller than any array in `d`. It could be the largest or even `[nil]*(d.map(&:size).max)`.

Comment: I left the answer intentionally obtuse so as to provide the shape of the solution without necessarily giving a good homework answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

You might reduce your array, splitting into the new subarray when needed:

```
my_array.each_with_object([]) do |e, acc|
  (
    acc.find { |a| !a.find { |ae| ae.casecmp(e).zero? } } ||
    (acc << []).last
  ) << e
end
#⇒ [["ZV2", "4Q3", "abDc", "zQ2", "Def"],
#   ["4q3", "Abdc", "def", "zv2"],
#   ["ABDC", "DeF", "zV2"],
#   ["DEF"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_array.each_with_object([]) do |s,a|
  d = s.downcase
  idx = a.find_index { |h| h.key?(d) == false }
  if idx.nil?
    a << { d=>s }
  else
    a[idx][d] = s
  end
end.map(&:values)
  #=> [["ZV2", "4Q3", "abDc", "zQ2", "Def"],
  #    ["4q3", "Abdc", "def", "zv2"],
  #    ["ABDC", "DeF", "zV2"],
  #    ["DEF"]]
```

See [Array#find_index](https://ruby-doc.org//core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-find_index).

I can best explain how this works by adding some `puts` statements. Interested readers can run the code below to observe the step-by-step calculations.

```
arr = my_array.each_with_object([]) do |s,a|
  d = s.downcase
  puts "s=#{s}, a=#{a}, d=#{d}"
  idx = a.find_index { |h| h.key?(d) == false }
  puts "s=#{s}, a=#{a}, idx.nil?=#{idx.nil?}, idx=#{idx}"
  if idx.nil?
    a << { d=>s }
  else
    a[idx][d] = s
  end
  puts "  after case a=#{a.to_s}"
end
arr.map(&:values)
```